# Socket.io - How to automatically emit an event after a period

Tags: socket.io

I am developing a chat app. I want socket server automatically emit an event after x mins to refresh message's created time. For example, i send a msg (0 seconde ago) after 5mins, socket emit event so that client refresh the messges to re-display the time ( 5 minutes ago). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use setInterval like so:

```
    function myfunction() {
       // emitevent
    }

    setInterval(myfunction, milliseconds);
```